# Project status change trigger

Tags: trigger, email

I have project object and client object is a look up field in the project object.

i need a trigger where if the status of the project is changed to Completed. an email should be sent to the email address in the client object linked to the project

below is what i wrote, i am not recieving any error but no email is getting fired

any help please

```
trigger Projectclientemail1 on Project__c (after update) {
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
Set<Id> ProjectId = new Set<Id>();
  Project__c[] projectlist = new Project__c[]{};
 for(Client__c Cl : [SELECT Client_Email__c FROM Client__c WHERE Id IN :ProjectId]) {
sendTo.add(Cl.Client_Email__c);
 for(Project__c p : Trigger.new) {
    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter) {
    {
       if(p.Status__c == 'Completed')
      List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();     
mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
  mail.setSubject('Project status changed'); 
  String body = 'Project status is changed';
  mail.setHtmlBody(body);
mail.setReplyTo('2323@gmail.com');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('Official mail from Knightcapitalfunding');
  mails.add(mail);
}
}
Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
}
 }
}
```

Comment: You should consider moving most of this code into a handler class. The trigger itself should be very little code. Some best practices: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000DBl8IAG

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the pasting of your code originally in your question is how it is formatted on your end, or just how it ended up here, but it was hard to read.  Lukas' edit improved the formatting, but if I take it and format it with consistent placement of curly braces and indenting, I get this:

```apex
 1 trigger Projectclientemail1 on Project__c (after update) {
 2     List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
 3     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
 4     List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
 5     Set<Id> ProjectId = new Set();
 6     Project__c[] projectlist = new Project__c[]{};
 7     for(Client__c Cl : [SELECT Client_Email__c FROM Client__c WHERE Id IN :ProjectId]) {
 8         sendTo.add(Cl.Client_Email__c);
 9         for(Project__c p : Trigger.new) { 
10             if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter) { 
11                 {
12                     if(p.Status__c == 'Completed') 
13                         List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
14                     mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
15                     mail.setSubject('Project status changed');
16                     String body = 'Project status is changed';
17                     mail.setHtmlBody(body);
18                     mail.setReplyTo('2323@gmail.com');
19                     mail.setSenderDisplayName('Official mail from Knightcapitalfunding');
20                     mails.add(mail);
21                 }
22             }
23             Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
24         }
25     }
26 }
```

I see a few issues:

1. Notice your `if` statement on *line 12* has no opening curly brace, which means that only the next line, *line 13*, is conditional.  *Lines 14-20* will run even if `p.Status__c` does not equal "Completed".

   And you get no error in this case because `sendTo` was initialized in *line 4* and so exists.
2. There appears to be a stray `{` on *line 11*.  This creates a code block inside the `if` (from *line 10*) code block.  Code blocks are legal, so no error here.

   You should move the `{` from *line 11* and put it at the end of the *line 12* `if` statement so that it looks like this:

   ```apex
   ...
              if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter) { 
                  if(p.Status__c == 'Completed') {
                      List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
                      mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
                      mail.setSubject('Project status changed');
                      String body = 'Project status is changed';
                      mail.setHtmlBody(body);
                      mail.setReplyTo('2323@gmail.com');
                      mail.setSenderDisplayName('Official mail from Knightcapitalfunding');
                      mails.add(mail);
                  }
              }
   ...
   ```
3. Looking back at the code above with line numbers, on *line 13*, when you create your List within the inner `if` statement, you are naming it `sendTo` which already exists.  So by doing so, you are creating a new `sendTo` within the scope of the `if` statement. This `sendTo` will not contain the value you added to `sendTo` on *line 8*. (The original `sendTo` will retain the value from *line 8* but will be in a different scope. When you exit this `if` statement where the 2nd `sendTo` was created, the original `sendTo` will still be there with its original value.)

Therefore, when `p.Status__c == 'Completed'`, you are using an empty List in *line 14*.

If you mean to re-use `sendTo`, don't re-initialize it. If you mean to use a "fresh" list inside the `if` statement, name it something else.

Comment: thank you Moonpie for the response. I am fairly new to salesforce. i have tried it again and it is giving me error, not sure what i am doing wrong